# unconfirmed transaction for over 2 days what to do?

Tags: electrum

sent from exchange to wallet  2 days ago still not confirmed ?
https://blockchain.info/tx-index/277169110

Answer (score 0):

The recommended fee for a transaction is of 450 satoshis ber byte.

Your transaction is 226 byte long.

450 x 226 = 101700 shatishi

101700 shatoshi = 0.00101700 Bitcoin

The transaction fee you included is of 0.0003842 Bitcoin which is 0.0006328 BTC lower than the recommended.

I wouldn't be surprised if you had to wait even more.

Data source: [bitcoinfees](https://bitcoinfees.21.co/)

Answer (score 0):

All you can do now is that You need to wait!!!!! For a looooooong time. Probably will never get through, then your wallet should refund you For a looooooong time. As for now, 170 sat/B is not high enough a fee to get process, 450 sat/B is recommended. 170 sat/B give you the processing time from 60-Infinite minutes. If you have paid 450 sat/B, then processing time would be about 60 minutes. so basically you are fked if the seller need to get pay soon.